# Android Studio: How to send, and recieve a Class in diferent Activities

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

Im making a quiz game with questions on diferent topics
For Example i have activities for these topics: Flags, Capitals, Population, Economy, Continent, etc.

And i have one single ResultActivity to obtain the Score of the quiz.
The ResultActivity has a PLAY AGAIN button.

On the FlagsActivity i have this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ResultActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("RIGHT_ANSWER_COUNT", score);
intent.putExtra("NAME_ACTIVITY", "FlagsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

On the CapitalActivity i have this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ResultActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("RIGHT_ANSWER_COUNT", score);
intent.putExtra("NAME_ACTIVITY", "CapitalActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

etc.....

On the ResultActivity i have this code:

```
    activity = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME_ACTIVITY");


public void playAgain(View view){

        if(activity.equals("FlagsActivity")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FlagsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if(activity.equals("CapitalActivity")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if(activity.equals("PopulationActivity")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PopulationActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if(activity.equals("EconomyActivity")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EconomyActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if(activity.equals("ContinentActivity")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContinentActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Basically im sending an Intent with a String containing the name of the activity, then on the Result Activity evaluating with "if" the String = That activity name, start the activity.

What i want to do is someting like this:

On the Flags Activity:

```
Intent(getApplicationContext(),ResultActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(FlagsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

On the CapitalActivity:

```
Intent(getApplicationContext(),ResultActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(CapitalActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

On the Result Activity:

```
activity = getIntent();


public void playAgain(View view){

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activity);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

So that i can create as many quiz activities without having to create an "if" statement on the ResultActivity for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the class name as a string and use reflection to look up a class object for that type.  Something like this:

```
Class classToLoad = Class.forName(getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME_ACTIVITY"));
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  classToLoad);
startActivity(intent);
```

I would pass the fully qualified class name to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the `String` of activity name to the Result activity, and get its corresponding class name using reflection:

```
String strActivity = "com.package.FlagsActivity";
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ResultActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("activity_name", strActivity );
startActivity(intent);


String activityName = getIntent().getStringExtra("activity_name");   
Class<?> myClass = Class.forName(activityName );
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), myClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

In the Results Activity

```
public static void toActivity(Context context, final Class ActivityToOpen){

    //whatever awesome code you would like to perform

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityToOpen);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In the originating Activity (Flags Activity for example)

```
ResultsActivity.toActivity(FlagsActivity.this, FlagActivity.class);
```

Check for typos... I kinda winged this :) 
You should be able to call from any originating Activity without if statement.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the data

```
String activity;
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null){
        activity = bundle.getString("NAME_ACTIVITY");
    }
```